# Phonegap App Orientation Handling

Tags: android, cordova, android-orientation

Actually iam forcing my phonegap app for android version to be in portrait mode only but i was  given requirement that one screen is to be in landscape mode. I got struck here. Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: so less info.. no wonder u got no answers

Answer (score 0):

You can either make BODY rotation to 90 deg with CSS3. Like:

```
body {transform:rotate(90deg);}
```